# How can I compare objects of two different classes?

Tags: c++

I want to make a program where you can input some random names, then in the next few lines input `father > son/daughter`. Then the program will search for the father from the first input.

Example:

> mia ana
>     shane > ana

Output will be:

> ana < shane

This is the program I made (note `anak`=child; `ayah`=father; `nama`=name):

```
using namespace std;

class status { 
public:
string ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3;
status (const string& inayah="", const string& inanak1="", const string& inanak2="", const string& inanak3="") : ayah(inayah), anak1(inanak1), anak2(inanak2), anak3(anak3){}
};

class populasi {
string nama1, nama2, nama3, nama4, nama5, nama6;
public:
populasi (const string& innama1="",const string& innama2="",const string& innama3="", const string& innama4="",const string& innama5="",const string& innama6="")
: nama1(innama1), nama2(innama2), nama3(innama3), nama4(innama4), nama5(innama5), nama6(innama6){}



void cek(const status& x)
{
    if( x.anak1() == nama1() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak1() == nama2() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak1() == nama3() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak1() == nama4() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak1() == nama5() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak1() == nama6() ) cout << x.anak1() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;

    if( x.anak2 == nama1() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak2 == nama2() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak2 == nama3() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak2 == nama4() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak2 == nama5() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak2 == nama6() ) cout << x.anak2() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;

    if( x.anak3 == nama1() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak3 == nama2() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak3 == nama3() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak3 == nama4() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak3 == nama5() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    if( x.anak3 == nama6() ) cout << x.anak3() << " < " << x.ayah() << endl;
    };  
};

 int main()
 {  
string nama1, nama2, nama3, nama4, nama5, nama6;
fscanf ( stdin, " %s %s %s %s %s %s", &nama1, &nama2, &nama3, &nama4, &nama5, &nama6); 
populasi a (nama1, nama2, nama3, nama4, nama5, nama6);

string ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3;
fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status b ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status c ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status d ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status e ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status f ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

fscanf ( stdin, " %s > %s %s %s", &ayah, &anak1, &anak2, &anak3); 
status g ( ayah, anak1, anak2, anak3);

a.cek(b);
a.cek(c);
a.cek(d);
a.cek(e);
a.cek(f);
a.cek(g);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe start by renaming your variables in English words so we can at least understand what each one is supposed to store. Also, and if I do actually understand your question, I think you should invest some time learning about containers.

Comment: Please make the problem statement more clear . Both the question statement and the example does not say clearly what you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you're really going about this in a very "C" style, and missing out on the C++ Standard Library's facilities for parsing input, storing text, and associative containers (that let you store values assocated with "keys" then find them later by specifying the same "key").

Given each person only has one type of data associated with them - their name - there's no need for or benefit from a user-defined class in this program.  The `std::string` class can easily store their name.  Your classes stored multiple names, but the C++ standard library containers are better able to do this.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
     std::string first_line;
     if (!getline(std::cin, line))
     {
          std::cerr << "failed to read a line of names\n";
          return 1;
     }

     // read and remember father/child relationships...
     typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;
     Map child_to_father;
     std::string father, child;
     char c = '>';
     while (iss >> father >> c && c == '>' && iss >> child)
         child_to_father[child] = father;
     if (!is.eof() || is.bad() || c != '>')
     {
         std::cerr << "error reading 'father > child' line\n";
         return 1;
     }

     // now report the matches for names on the first line...
     std::istringstream iss(first_line);
     while (iss >> child)
     {
          Map::const_iterator i = child_to_father.find(name);
          if (i != child_to_father.end())
               std::cout << child << " < " << father << '\n';
     }
}
```